# how to style a php form using css

Tags: php

i have made a form using php this is my code

```
<?php

echo "<div class='error_msg'>";
echo validation_errors();
echo "</div>";
echo form_open('user_authentication/new_user_registration');

echo form_label('Create Username : ');
echo"<br/>";
echo form_input('username');
echo "<div class='error_msg'>";
if (isset($message_display)) {
echo $message_display;
}
echo "</div>";
echo"<br/>";
echo form_label('Email : ');
echo"<br/>";
$data = array(
'type' => 'email',
'name' => 'email_value'
);
echo form_input($data);
echo"<br/>";
echo"<br/>";
echo form_label('Password : ');
echo"<br/>";
echo form_password('password');
echo"<br/>";
echo"<br/>";
echo form_submit('submit', 'Sign Up');
echo form_close();
?>
```

the form is supposed register new users 
how can i style this form using css given that there is no html in the code.

Comment: The div and br tags *are* HTML. So, you do have HTML in the code. What you will likely do is include this script in a web page. Then, that web page will include a CSS document that styles the form's ID or class. You will, of course, need to wrap the form in a div or span or table and give it an ID or class.

Comment: Well first you have to tell your form that it should load some css to use http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/adding-css-to-html-with-link-embed-inline-and-import

Answer (score 0):

The `echo();` function you are using essentially prints HTML, this HTML can be styled by including a style sheet (Google CSS basics and you will quickly find out how to do this).

I would advise running this script and using the web inspector of your chosen browser to look at the HTML code you have created using your PHP code. Again, if your not familiar with the web inspector Google how to open it on your chosen browser.

Hope this clarifies things a bit :)